# Service broker - multiple queues vs one queue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am going to create a service broker to connect several instances, maybe I will show it in the picture
[Service broker - instance connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOj3h.png)

Instance A is target, instances from B to I are Initiator's , all instaces are on diferrent servers.
The first thought came to me to do on the target server (instance A) a separate queue for each instance because each instance has its own queue, in case of problems I can always turn off this problem queue, while the remaining queues can continue to function.

Here my questions arise:

1. Is it a good idea or should I use one queue?

If the idea with many queues is fine, now I have another problem. I use the same procedure for all queues to retrieve data from the queue but to retrieve the data from the queue I have to indicate the name of the queue that called the procedure:

```
WAITFOR
    ( RECEIVE TOP(1)
        @RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle,
        @RecvReqMsgTemp = message_body,
        @RecvReqMsgName = message_type_name,
        @ServiceName = service_name
      FROM **'queue_name'**
```

So the next question is:

2. Is it possible to retrieve the queue name that calls the procedure?

Comment: Tell me more about wanting to prohibit a given initiator from being able to send messages to the central target. Like, under what circumstances would you want to do that?

Comment: For example, instance C sends me wrong or outdated data and can not see it, in which case I will need to stop the transfer of data through this instance without stopping the data from other instances. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like your target should detect that condition and send a message back to the initiator at which point they act accordingly.